# Anchor Points Not Working using fullPage onLeave

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I had everything working just fine with my menu and anchor points, but after adding the following code the links stopped working:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var leavingSection = $(this);

        //after leaving section 2
        if(index == 1 && direction =='down'){
            $('header').addClass('active');
        }

        else if(index == 2 && direction == 'up'){
            $('header').removeClass('active');

        }
    }
});
```

My intention is to hide my header and only show it after the second section, which happens but the anchor points aren't working anymore.

My header html

```
<header>
    <ul id="myMenu">
        <li data-menuanchor="topo" class="active"><a href="#topo"><img src="img/dcb-white.svg"></a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="contato"><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="sobre"><a href="#sobre">Sobre Mim</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="historico"><a href="#historico">Histórico</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="topo" class="active"><a href="#topo">Topo</a></li>
     </ul>
</header>
```

header css

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    z-index:9;
    text-align:center;
    color: #fff;
    top:0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}

header.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically you are not telling fullpage.js you want to use anchors.

You have to use the `anchors` option in your initialization  (that you are not using) or rather use the `data-anchor` attribute in each of your sections. (which seems you are not using either)

Read more about it [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

> **anchors:** (default []) Defines the anchor links (#example) to be shown on the URL for each section. Anchors value should be unique. The position of the anchors in the array will define to which sections the anchor is applied. (second position for second section and so on). Using anchors forward and backward navigation will also be possible through the browser. This option also allows users to bookmark a specific section or slide. Be careful! anchors can not have the same value as any ID element on the site (or NAME element for IE). Now anchors can be defined directly in the HTML structure by using the attribute data-anchor as explained here.

Answer (score 0):

In was able to accomplish the effect I wanted using css but I still don't understand why onLeave code is not working:

[Watch this video to understand how I did it: youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M](http://youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M)